# cassanda cluster on AWS showing a total Owns > 100% in nodetool

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra

I setup a 3 node cassandra cluster on ec2 and noticed somethign weird when I do a `./nodetool status`. The `Owns (effective)` is > 100% in totoal.

```
[root@ip-10-205-116-141 bin]# ./nodetool status
Datacenter: us-east
===================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.205.117.246  85.73 KB   1       25.0%             72e2394c-bd17-4fe5-aee5-bf4cf8486153  1c
UN  10.205.119.47   89.91 KB   1       75.0%             7f39be54-5d74-433c-98e1-8aeff64ff795  1c
UN  10.205.116.141  171.17 KB  256     100.0%            ce5eb89b-d806-4d70-ab14-99df3bdee7c8  1c
```

shouldn't it be 33% each?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that almost all tokens are assigned to `10.205.116.141`. Usually it's not desired situation. Rebalance your token assignment to fix it.

Comment: So do I need to regenerate 3 token then and configure that in the cassandra.yaml file again?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Read http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/balancing-your-cassandra-cluster and http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeVnodesUsing_c.html if you are using Cassandra vnodes.

Comment: I followed this guide here http://www.tanzirmusabbir.com/2013/02/install-cassandra-cluster-within-30.html...but I'm not using the Datastax version. I'm using the one direclty off of apache's site...the only token setup I did was generate 3 murmur tokens and then set the initial token value of each node....guess I'm missing a step? I tried to look at the link but that uses Opscenter which is not included in teh apache version. How do I do it manually?

Comment: Try to restart each node and run on each node nodetool cleanup and later nodetool repair. If you have followed mentioned tutorial, you aren't using vnodes. In that case can try adding new node as stated here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddRplSingleTokenNodes.html (it's also applicable for non-Datastax Cassandra).